# OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files when using With....as: expression

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

despite i am using `with....as:` expression to gaurantee that the pool and consequently all of its processes are closed, however, when i run the code, i receive the error posted below.
to solve this issue, i referred to some posts in stackoverflow and referred to a tutorial called "superFast python", and as a result, there was a common concordance in the posts i check, since using the `with...as:` closes the pool automatically.

please let me know why i am still getting that error despite using `with...as:` expression

***codee**:

```
with Pool(processes=self.__processCount,initializer=self.initPool,initargs=(arg0,arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6,arg7,arg8,arg9,)) as GridCells10mX10mIteratorPool.__pool:
        self.__chunkSize = PoolUtils.getChunkSizeForLenOfIterables(lenOfIterablesList=self.__maxNumOfCellsVertically*self.__maxNumOfCellsHorizontally,cpuCount=self.__cpuCount)
        iterables = self.__yieldIterables()
        logger.info(f"GridCells10mX10mIteratorPool.self.__chunkSize(task per processor):{self.__chunkSize}")
        for res in GridCells10mX10mIteratorPool.__pool.map(func=self.run,iterable=iterables,chunksize=self.__chunkSize):
            ...
            ...
            ...
GridCells10mX10mIteratorPool.__pool.close()
GridCells10mX10mIteratorPool.__pool.terminate()
GridCells10mX10mIteratorPool.__pool.join()
            
def __yieldIterables(self):
    cnt = -1
    for i in range(GridCells10mX10mIteratorModel.getStrtRowIdx(),GridCells10mX10mIteratorModel.getMaxSpanInHeight(),GridCells10mX10mIteratorModel.getVerticalStep()):
        for j in range(GridCells10mX10mIteratorModel.getStrtColIdx(),GridCells10mX10mIteratorModel.getMaxSpanInWidth(),GridCells10mX10mIteratorModel.getHorizontalStep()):
            cnt+=1
            yield(i,j,cnt)
```

***error***:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 119, in Pool
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 212, in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 303, in _repopulate_pool
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 277, in _Popen
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 69, in _launch
  OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

Comment: IIRC linux systems limit the number of open file descriptors to 1024 per process. If you open more files than that you'll get that error. If you need to process more files than the limit you can batch your processing but the descriptors don't get closed until the context manager exits scope.

Comment: @JaredSmith i am working on a server with super configurations, it has 128 processor.i was thinking that siince i have 128 processors, and since i have chunck-size equal to number of iterables"iterables.length"/(128-1), i will have only 127 opened files..am i wrong?